# Magento - Trouble with setting up Model Read Adapter

Tags: orm, frameworks, model, magento

I was following through on Alan Storm's tutorial on [Magento's Model and ORM basics](http://alanstorm.com/magento_models_orm) and I've run into a bit of a problem. When I get to the portion where I load from the Model for the first time I get this error "Fatal error: Call to a member function load() on a non-object...". I've reset everything already and tried again from scratch but I still get the same problem. My code looks like this:

```
 $params = $this->getRequest()->getParams();
 $blogpost = Mage::getModel('weblog/blogpost');
 var_dump($blogpost);
 echo("Loading the blogpost with an ID of ".$params['id']);
 $blogpost->load($params['id']);
```

As you can see I dumped the contents of $blogpost and it shows that it is just a boolean false. My guess is that there's either a problem with the connection to the database or, for some reason, the code for Mage::getModel() didn't get installed correctly.

**EDIT** - Adding Code

There's so many that I just decided to pastebin them lol

[app/code/local/Ahathaway/Weblog/controllers/IndexController.php](http://pastebin.com/vyGJLuLW)

[app/code/local/Ahathaway/Weblog/etc/config.xml](http://pastebin.com/pVYg6U6g)

[app/code/local/Ahathaway/Weblog/Model/Blogpost.php](http://pastebin.com/j3Hhd8DD)

[app/etc/modules/Ahathaway_Weblog.xml](http://pastebin.com/x3ei4VNM)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Model/Blogpost.php file should actually be Model/Mysql4/Blogpost.php, and you are missing the real Model/Blogpost.php.

Comment: I apologize, what do you mean the real Model/Blogpost.php? Is there one that's included in the Magento package?

Comment: Take a look at Alan Storm's tutorial. There are two different files called Blogpost.php:
The model: Model/Blogpost.php
The resource model: Model/Mysql4/Blogpost.php
You have:
Resource model in wrong place: Model/Blogpost.php

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that Mage cannot find your model class. Double check the module/model name and also verify if the model is in a correct place in the filesystem (it should be in app/code/local/Weblog/Model/Blogpost.php).

You also need to check if your config.xml correctly defines your model classes. It would be best if you could past your config.xml and your model class...

Comment: I added the code to the post. In your comment you said the path should be app/code/local/Weblog/Model/Blogpost.php, shouldn't it also have the namespace like mine does?

Answer (score 1):

A quick glance reveals you're missing the model resource.  Go back to the section around the following code example

```
File: app/code/local/Alanstormdotcom/Weblog/Model/Mysql4/Blogpost.php

class Alanstormdotcom_Weblog_Model_Mysql4_Blogpost extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract{
    protected function _construct()
    {
        $this->_init('weblog/blogpost', 'blogpost_id');
    }   
}
```

Comment: Perfect, thank you! For whatever reason I got confused about the resource model deal haha.

Comment: "Models" give you the logical model ("get the email address, get the title, etc.") Resource Models do the actual querying to the database.  The theory is you can drop in a new resource model that readys from another database version/package, without having to change your base model class.